# Can we play Conquerers if we don't have Cities and Knights?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

We have the base *Catan* and the *Cities and Knights: Legend of the Conquerers* scenario extension set. But we don't have the *Cities and Knights* set. We also have the *Seafearers* extension. Is there a way to play *The Conquerors* without the *Cities and Knights* extension?

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not

> **THIS IS A SCENARIO FOR THE CATAN CITIES AND KNIGHTS BOARD GAME EXPANSION**: In order to play with this Scenario, you will need the following 2 Games: CATAN Base Game and CATAN Cities and Knights Board Game Expansion.`

Quote from this location: [https://www.amazon.com/Catan-Cities-Knights-Conquerors-Scenario/dp/B084HNCLRV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084HNCLRV)